# What is the definition of 外省?

Tags: word

In the following answer in [知乎](https://www.zhihu.com/question/21991526), the respondent said the following to a question asking how much it costs to live in Paris:

> 外省7-8万，巴黎10W+

I would like to know what 外省 means here. 省 means `province` so it is clear enough for me that 外省 at least doesn't express the metropolitan place like in Paris.

However, what kind of areas or districts 外省 mean? Is it a suburban or rural? If you relate it to Paris, does it point to somewhere except the central of Paris but in the il-de-france region, or outside of the il-de-france but still in Paris, or totally outside of the Paris?

Comment: see e.g. bkrs: other provinces (i.e., beyond the capital); provinces other than where one is

1) 谓中枢机构之外的官署。
2) 本省以外的省份。
3) 京都以外的地方各省。
住在外省
жить на периферии (live on the periphery)

Comment: In French, and particularly in France, the expression "dans les provinces" is still in current use, and is similarly nebulous.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

外省(outside provinces / other provinces) refers to all provinces other than 本省(own province) - the province you are currently residing. In this case, 外省 means any province other than Île-de-France where Paris is located in.

Paris is a city, so "*巴黎10W+*" refers to the living cost in Paris only. The quote also mentioned cost outside of Île-de-France "*外省7-8万*" but did not mention the cost to live in Île-de-France itself.

Either the writer presumed the cost to live in Île-de-France is the same as in Paris, or he thought Paris is a province.